# Is this the right way of segregating members and non members from a contact list?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, caching, memcached

**Scenario**

Almost every social app does this, they take your contact list, and tell you who among them are a member of the service and who are not. From what I have seen, they do this very very fast.

For the sake of simplicity, lets assume that the contacts are only emails, I would do a select query like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM account WHERE email="abc@xyz.com"`. Now, this approach resulted in very large response time, and it doesn't look like an efficient approach either.

So, the next approach that I took was that on every registration, I store the `email_id` as the Key and the generated `account_id` after registration as the value in memcached. This way, I didn't bother doing an SQL query, I just do a `memcache->get(email)` for each email, and if I get a `false` response, I would consider him to be a non-member, and if I get a response, he is a member. This makes the whole process almost 10x faster.

The SQL approach took about 13 secs for a contact list of about 400 contacts and a dataset of over 100,000 rows in the account table, while the Memcache approach took mere 1-2 secs for the same data.

Now, there are two problem that the memcache approach brings along with its speed. One, if the memcache was flushed(for any reason, upgrading or maintainance, or memory full etc.), even a member would be segregated as a non-member. For this I used a memcache warmup script which will get all the members, and set the required key value every time the cache was flushed.

**Question**

And the main problem that I need an answer to is that, if the memcache get returns `false`, I cannot be 100% sure that he is not a member, because the `key` might have been flushed or there might have been an error connecting to the memcache server etc.
So, how does everyone do this check so efficiently and so fast? Whatsapp, Google Allo etc?

Currently, I am using PHP 5.4, MySQL and Memcache, but I am open to any programming language, as long as it does the job efficiently.
Also, note that the Table has been properly indexed to optimize the query.

Comment: The 'right' way depends entirely on your project. Also 1k+ rep and you don't know better than to tag every OS out there except MySQL and include a MySQL query as example code. I'm only speaking on behalf of iOS community - this doesn't relate and you should know better than to ask for code review. There's another site on stackexchange for that purpose.

Comment: @soulshined If it doesn't relate to you, then you can just pass it off, I have put ios and android, because there might be developer who have done this because in the end, the mobile end is involved in this. Moreover, I did not tag mysql because, it was the least important thing in the question and SO does not let me tag more than 5. Anyway, ty for the suggestion, I'll look for the site that you mentioned too.

Comment: You can try simulating an INTERSECT call in MySQL using a subquery.

Comment: Mobile is usually the easiest thing to work into a project as long as you have your BaaS i's dotted and t's crossed. In my opinion. Any mobile OS can make a cloud related request, whatever the syntax is, but your question had iOS tagged so I responded. But more importantly im just answering your question, whatever is right depends on your project. How 'they' do it depends on numerous things. Server location, rate-free limits, how their apps are designed etc. usually with apps your only displaying x rows at a time. So for iOS you load them asynchronously not collectively

Comment: @soulshined I see. This looks more like a question/discussion for the programming stackexchange site.

Comment: @npace I'll look into that. Thanks!

Comment: You have got an index on your email column?  Do you re-use a prepared statement?  Could you chunk using WHERE IN?

Comment: @Progrock Yes, there is an index on the email column.  I just checked, I am not reusing the prepared statement, but I am preparing it again for every contact, is that an issue? I can try a Where in, i think it's a good idea.

Comment: I just read in 'Mysql Cookbook', that Mysql doesn't build query plans in advance so you won't see much improvement reusing the statement, but other dbs you may.

Comment: 13 sec?  1-2 sec?  Neither of those make sense.  Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the `SELECT`.